# Remove Binary while Waiting for Review

Tags: xcode, app-store, itunes, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I have just uploaded a binary file for review.
The status for my app now is Waiting for Review. But i discovered a bug which i should fix it before submitting but i can't find where the remove binary is located.
The last submit, it was under the Version section, But now it is just disappeared!!
I have tried lot of research and all refers to the old iTunes design, and just found 1 solution which was under the version tab which is not found in my case now.
Does anyone know where is it now with all these changes made by iTunes every day? or it is delayed more than 1 hour to appear ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same problem and could not found where to Reject the binary.
Finally I downloaded an iTunes Connect app from App Store and rejected the binary by it.

Comment: Thank you:) you saved me from lot of troubles